# cannot select another workbook when macro enabled workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro enabled workbook that uses code to set a timer - this is a shared book and often people will be in the book and leave their desk etc.  It is set to save & close after 30 minutes of inactivity.  That function seems to work fine but the problem I am running into is that when I have other workbooks open I cannot select them, either by clicking on the tile (Windows 7) or by alt+tab, the only way to move around is ctrl+shift.  If it was just me using the workbook that would not be an issue - does anybody know why this is happening?  Code posted below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
StartTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
StartTimer
End Sub


Const idleTime = 1800 'seconds
Dim Start
Sub StartTimer()
Start = Timer
Do While Timer < Start + idleTime
DoEvents
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To start off with, I'm not entirely sure why you're getting that behaviour, but please keep reading. I *suspect* it has something to do with your *busy-wait* loop (the one with the `DoEvents`), but that's just a hunch. Someone else might have a (better) explanation.

Anyway, perhaps using [`Application.OnTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165(v=office.14).aspx) is a better approach. You can schedule an operation to happen at a certain time or interval and there's an option to cancel and replace a previously scheduled operation. You'll need that facility in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event handler.

In short, you can do the following:

1. Add a new routine to save and exit the workbook, let's call it: `SaveWorkbookAndExit`. This will be called by `OnTime` later.
2. Replace the contents of your `Workbook_SheetChange` event handler as follows:

   ```
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), _
                      "SaveWorkbookAndExit", _
                      Schedule:=False
   ```

   This basically schedules the routine `SaveWorkbookAndExit` to be called in 30 minutes from now. Notice the `Schedule:=False` -- it signifies that a previously set procedure should be cleared/cancelled, which is very important.
3. Also add the same code as above to your `Workbook_Open` event handler. **Unlike above though, note that you should set `Schedule:=True` in here!**

And that's it. When the workbook is opened, a new `SaveWorkbookAndExit` operation is scheduled. Then, every time you go into `Workbook_SheetChange`, the previously scheduled operation will be cancelled and a new one will be scheduled in its place.

I haven't tested any of this, but I hope you get the idea. Please let me know if you need me to explain something further.

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I am a bit fuzzy on VB so I might need some clarify.  When I setup the code above I first double clicked "ThisWorkbook" and entered the first section of code, I then entered the second section into a module and saved and it worked (besides the issue I had).  I tried the same order with the code you provided and I code "Compile Error Invalid outside procedure" I deleted what I originally had, should I have done that? Thanks again

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with VB but I do have basic programming knowledge - i am just reusing somebody's VBA code.  Thanks again